# Updating / Changing settings from client side in AspnetBoilerplate with Angular

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate

With Asp.net Boilerplate using the Angular / .net Core template I see there are a few client side functions {get, getBoolean, getInt} in the "setting" namespace that make it quite easy to get the settings but I do not see any documentation on updating those settings.

```
var currentColor = abp.setting.get("SiteColorPreference");
```

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Setting-Management

I was expecting to see similar set methods alongside the get methods. What am I missing or should I try to submit a PR for that functionality? Seems quite odd to have only getters and no setters.

Of course I can update the user service and create my own function to update the settings but that seems like it should be built into the framework just like the get methods.

Maybe this is not the correct place but the goal of the question is I want to utilize a local store for user variables. For instance a user might want to configure the UI and have a layout setting or each user has a setting for which account they are working on... in a nutshell something like Profile Provider:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.profile.sqlprofileprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2

##Update In then AspnetBoilerplate was not a solution I chose to use. I ended up building https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate which has more transparent and manageable code using a Blazor UI.

Comment: settings are not allowed to change by any user. so if you want to change a setting from client you need to check a permission or check a role. so it depends on your business logic. and the framework is not opinionated in that case.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu thanks for the response. I updated the question. But basically what mechanism in ABP is used like WebConfig User Profile settings?? I thought this was close to it

Answer (score 0):

You need to create [Application Service](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Application-Services) for your requirement. 
Let's investigate it for updating a user theme selection.

Create an application service called `UserPreferencesAppService` and add a method like `UpdateMyThemeId()`. And in your method set user's theme like below;

```
 public class UserPreferencesAppService: ApplicationService {

    const string AppPermissions.Pages_User_Settings = "AppPermissions.Pages.User.Settings"

    [AbpAuthorize(AppPermissions.Pages_User_Settings)]
    private async Task UpdateMyThemeId(string themeId)
    {
           await SettingManager.ChangeSettingForUserAsync(user, "User.Theme.Selection", themeId);

    }
 }
```

PS: I wrote the code on top of my head.

Comment: Server side functionality seems quite clear for getting and setting data from the AbpSettings table, I basically already have that code done and running and I created a custom service on the client side to save. But that still leaves me thinking that there is missing default functionality on the client side, in my opion this framework should have something like that. It looks like you are a contributor on the repo / work for volosoft.  Is this functionality in your Asp.net zero product?

Comment: Nope! This would be a huge security hole

Comment: So what mechanism is provided for user profile settings??? Something similar to profile provider in web.config. That is real question that has not been addressed.